# Use of every site's primary color in "Questions", "Users", "Tags" and "Unanswered" numbering section

Tags: feature-request, design

In **every** Stack Exchange site, the "Questions", "Users", "Tags" and "Unanswered" pages have **orange** color in the **numbering section** at the bottom.

For example,

The workplace  [image]

Meta [image]

Mathematics[image]

Instead of the pre-existing **orange** color (Stack Overflow's primary color), every site's own **primary color** could be applied to the numbering section.